# Is it possible to set a project-specific font in Sublime (2)?

Tags: sublime-text-2, sublime-text

Is it possible to set a project-specific font in Sublime (2)?

I just naively tried adding this to the config it give you under `Project > Edit Project`:

```
{
"font_face": "monospace"
}
```

(Which was empty before.)

But no banana. I don't see anything else obvious to try, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it just needed to be:

```
{
    "settings":
        {
            "font_face": "monospace"
        }
}
```